# What is the Rubiest way to check strictly for false value (and exclude nil)?

Tags: ruby

What is the Rubiest way check that a value is `false` and not `nil` (which is a falsy value)?

example using a fictional method `false?`:

```
a = false
a.false? # should return true
a = nil
a.false? # should return false
```

Comment: Use `a == false`.

Comment: I would argue that the Ruby way is to not differentiate between false and falsey.

Comment: I agree with @spickermann, I can't think of a case where I've needed to explicitly check false.

Comment: There's one popular use-case: prior to Rails 5, a return value of `false` from a callback indicated an error (halting the callback chain) whereas `nil` was ignored. This was changed (or fixed) – the callbacks now have to `throw :abort`.

Comment: The context is similar to what is described by @SimpleLime. Say you have a list of services represented as a hashmap. The services may or may not have implemented an `option`. If they do, the value of `option` may be `true` or `false`. If the service has not implemented `option`, calling `service[:option]` returns `nil` because it does not have a key `option`. If they have, calling `service[:option]` may return `true` or `false`. In the example above we need to retrieve only the services whose `option` is implemented and set to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

So far we have four different approaches:

```
a == false                 # credits to @Ilya

a.is_a?(FalseClass)
FalseClass === a

a.instance_of?(FalseClass) # credits to @Ilya

a.nil? ^ !a
```

Comment: also `false.instance_of?(FalseClass)`

Answer (score 2):

I concur with [@spickermann's comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699124/what-is-the-rubiest-way-to-check-strictly-for-false-value-and-exclude-nil#comment82360004_47699124) that the most Ruby way would be to *not* distinguish between `nil` and `false`.

The most *OO* way would be to allow an object to decide for itself whether it is false or not, just the way you are doing in your question: by responding to a `false?` message.

```
class TrueClass
  def true?
    true
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def false?
    true
  end
end

class Object
  def true?
    false
  end

  def false?
    false
  end
end
```

If you want to be a nice Ruby citizen, you encapsulate these monkeypatches in a mixin, so that they show up in the ancestors chain:

```
module StrictlyTrue
  def true?
    true
  end
end

class TrueClass
  include StrictlyTrue
end

module StrictlyFalse
  def false?
    true
  end
end

class FalseClass
  include StrictlyFalse
end

module NeitherFalseNorTrue
  def true?
    false
  end

  def false?
    false
  end
end

class Object
  include NeitherFalseNorTrue
end
```

And if you want to be totally nice, you can wrap this in a Refinement:

```
module StrictlyTrue
  def true?
    true
  end
end

module StrictlyFalse
  def false?
    true
  end
end

module NeitherFalseNorTrue
  def true?
    false
  end

  def false?
    false
  end
end

module StrictBooleans
  refine TrueClass do
    include StrictlyTrue
  end

  refine FalseClass do
    include StrictlyFalse
  end

  refine Object do
    include NeitherFalseNorTrue
  end
end
```